# Reference file during subprocess (Python)

Tags: python, list, subprocess

Got list that gets written out to a file:

```
f=open('/tmp/list.txt','w')

f.write(list)
```

Contents of f needs to then be used in subprocess

```
process = subprocess.Popen('oscommand **--file=f**, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

How can contents of f be read in by oscommand ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass file name to sub-process command, not file object:

```
f = open('/tmp/list.txt','w')
f.write(list)
f.close()  # Make sure to close the file before call sub-process.
           # Otherwise, file content will not visible to sub-process.

process = subprocess.Popen('oscommand --file={}'.format(f.name),
                           shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```